# Android MapView zoom level doesn't exceed 19?

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, android-mapview

I am have just completed the [hello-mapview](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) tutorial and I am confused by the max zoom levels I can achieve.  The documentation for the MapController class states that the zoom can go up to level 21 however I cannot seem to exceed 19.  I also notice that the google Maps app from the market can go 2 extra zoom levels.  Is there a way that I can get these extra two zoom levels?

Comment: Aren't those levels depending on the details of the available map footage?

Comment: Yes, but in the google maps application there are clearly 2 extra zoom levels available.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
// decrement it until you get map visible...
controller.setZoom(map.getMaxZoomLevel() - 1)
```