# android mapview maximum zoom level only 19

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

I created a simple MapActivity on my android and discovered that its MapView can't be zoomed in to more than level 19. The zoom-in button just greys out. Calling the zoomIn() method is also to no effect, the level still stays at 19.

However, when I start the official Google Maps application, exactly the same area of the map successfully zooms in two more levels to 21.

Can anybody advise me on how I can zoom further in my own app? Am I missing setting some parameter explicitly (manifest, mapactivity, mapcontroller)? Really can't find out so far and feel quite confused about it, seeing the difference.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303862/android-mapview-zoom-level-doesnt-exceed-19) has been asked recently, but also stays unanswered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum zoom level depends on the area of the map you are in.

You can get the maximum zoom level available by calling `#getMaxZoomLevel()` in your `MapView`. That's the closest zoom you will be able to get, no matter what happens in the official Google Maps application.

Comment: Thank you mvg. Indeed, the getMaxZoomLevel returns 19. Just felt unhappy by seeing the two apps (not) allowing zooming further on the same piece of the map. However, just to place it here as a related thing I further found out, if I switch to the satellite view, I can zoom in to 21. Jumps back to 19 if I switch back to the map mode though.

Comment: Yes, the maximum zoom level also takes into account if you are in satellite view or not. getMaxZoomLevel will always return the appropiate value.