# How catch end of map resizing

Tags: android, android-mapview

To reduce processor's work to repaint my route on map, I use Path class. And I want to store one Path for one ZoomLevel.
I save my Path in SparseArray where key = ZoomLevel
and code looks like this

```
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        if (shadow){
            return;
        }
        else 
            if(route==null){
                return;
            }
            drawPath(mapView, canvas);
    }


    private void drawPath(MapView mv, Canvas canvas) {
        Point point = new Point();

         if (pathMap.get(gMapView.getZoomLevel())==null){           

            List<GeoPoint> list = null;
            Projection p = mv.getProjection();

            List<RouteMachine.Section> routeArray = route.getSections();
            p.toPixels(routeArray.get(0).getPoints().get(0), point);

            Point rememberThisPoint = new Point(point.x,point.y);

            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(point.x,point.y);
            for (RouteMachine.Section section : routeArray) {
                list = section.getPoints();
                for (int i=1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    p.toPixels(list.get(i), point);
                    path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
                }
            }
            pathMap.put(gMapView.getZoomLevel(), path, rememberThisPoint);
         }
         else{
            mv.getProjection().toPixels(route.getSections().get(0).getPoints().get(0), point);
            pathMap.offset(gMapView.getZoomLevel(),point);
         }
        canvas.drawPath(pathMap.get(gMapView.getZoomLevel()),mPaint);

        }
```

At different zoomLevels it works or doesn't work.
Level changes, but path looks like path from previous level. I think, it happens becose zoomLevel sometime changes before then map rapaints. And path calculating works between this two actions. ZoomLewel changed, but map hasn't rapainted yet.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with testing zoom level using `getZoomLevel()` is that after you request a zoom change it starts immediatly returning the new zoom level, but the map image goes through an animation of progressive size change that takes some time to complete.

However, the `getProjection().fromPixels()` returns the correct value of projection even during the animation and it can be used to check when animations ends.

I use the following line to test it:

```
    pathInitialLonSpan = projection.fromPixels(0,mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6() - 
            projection.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth(),mapView.getHeight()/2).getLongitudeE6();
```

It returns the longitude span at map center level. This value is will change during the zoom change animation and will be constant when zomm finishes.

I use it to validate the time when the animation ends and then build the path.

Regards.

Comment: Glad to help. If you make another question about how to improve performance in your code above, I'm sure you will get a couple of good hints :-)

Comment: If you are not planning to make a new question, I can make the suggestions for performance improvement as comment, but they will look messy. Just let me know.

Comment: Do I need to make new topic 'How can I improve perfomance next code ...' ?

Comment: Of cource it is interesting to me.

Comment: I'll try to put it here. You are ignoring the point in position 0 for every section. This is correct for first section, as the point on position 0 has been used in the `moveTo()`, but not for the other path sections. As you have many points probably you will not notice de mistake unless distance from point 0 and 1 is very large.

Comment: Second: if you are having paths with 70000+ points has stated in previous question, it worth to do one optimization not adding to the path points that are very close (let's say less than 2 or 3 pixels away). You can play with the maximum distance and check the visual effect. I personally find that point distance bellow 3 can be droped without visual quality impact.

Comment: To do it. you will need to keep track of last added and check distance to new point using something like `int distance = (pLastAdded.x - p1.x) * (pLastAdded.x - p1.x) + (pLastAdded.y - p1.y) * (pLastAdded.y - p1.y);` and you will get the square of distance (4 for distance 2, 9 for distance 3, ...). The you test distance before you add to path, and if added, you need to store this point as last point added.

Comment: Yes, first comment it's my fault. In my program Last point of section One == first point of section Two. But I needn't chek each time i>0. Better to start with i=1. I fixed this.

Comment: Second comment is very important for me. Thank You!

Comment: If you implement second comment, the problem refered in the first is automaticaly resolved, as the point will be ignored because distance will be 0;

Answer (score 0):

if u use ready library you can set the max , so you can didactic after that.

Look at [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32747/how-to-redraw-refresh-map-on-canvas-resize).

else

you can get max level like this:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405453/android-mapview-maximum-zoom-level-only-19)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146395/set-minimum-zoom-level-for-mapview)

Comment: No-no-no! I have to do some actions after map is resized. Ineedn't get maximum or minimum size level.