# Is there any way to zoom beyond the default zoom levels for the Google Maps in android V2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In my Android app, I have added GoogleMap using Google maps android API. I have sample tiles data available at 15 to 23 zoom levels. I have overlayed these tiles data on Google maps and I can see my tile data from zoom levels 15 t0 19 perfectly. But not able zoom in further to see tiles at zoom levels 20, 21, 22, 23 as Google maps max zoom level is 19. Is there way to address this ?

Any suggestions?

Comment: which google map version you worked on ?

Comment: refere this may help you, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405453/android-mapview-maximum-zoom-level-only-19)

Comment: Version is Google Maps Android V2 @krunalshah